# String.count() returning 0 even though word exists in file

Tags: python, string, substring

So this is a simple code trying to found the frequency of occurrences of a phrase ("every kind of asset") in a number of files.

```
import codecs
import glob
import os.path

filelocation = "C:\\Users\\Shoi\\Desktop\\mark project\\BITs\\*.txt"

for filepath in glob.glob(filelocation): # for each file
    FILE = codecs.open(filepath, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    if ("every kind of asset" in FILE.read().lower()):
        print ("Found in " + os.path.basename(filepath))
        freq = FILE.read().lower().count("every kind of asset")
        print(freq)
    else:
        print ("not found in " + os.path.basename(filepath))
```

However, even though the phrase is being found in some files ("Found in " file is printed) - the count function is returning and printing 0 always.

This code is searching for only a single phrase. When I iterate over a list of phrases, searching for each phrase in all the files - the count function returns perfectly correct frequency results for some phrases but returns 0 for others, even though the phrase exists in the file and it prints "found"

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two calls to `FILE.read()`. After the first one, the cursor will be at the end of the file, so the second call will return an empty string, which does not contain the string you're looking for at all.

Read the contents once and store them in a variable instead:

```
for filepath in glob.glob(filelocation): # for each file
    FILE = codecs.open(filepath, 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    contents = FILE.read().lower()
    if "every kind of asset" in contents:
        print("Found in " + os.path.basename(filepath))
        freq = contents.count("every kind of asset")
        print(freq)
    else:
        print("not found in " + os.path.basename(filepath))
```

Comment: Thank you for that. But the only reason I inserted the (if phrase in file) statement is because I the count function was returning 0 all the time and I wanted to check if some other staetment worked.

Initially, I just had one .read() call
    freq = FILE.read().count("my phrase)
    if(freq>0): print "found"
    else: print "not found"

But I was getting 0 as the result for many phrases even though they existed in the file.